# How to shrink /home and extend /root partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, disk-usage

[image: Here is a list]

[image]

I want to shrink my `/home` to about `15G`, and then extend my `/` to fill up that remaining space.

How can I do this?

In GParted, I can't seem to shrink `/home` because there is no free space after it I assume

The same goes for extending `/`

Comment: You cannot modify a mounted partition. Boot from a LiveUSB instead.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I just wasn't sure which commands I had to use. The gparted was just to show a visual in case it would be helpful

Comment: Not really, its quite outdated, there seems to be alot of confusion in the comments, and the instructions are very minimal

Comment: The [very first answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/19626) on that duplicate is very good, and not at all outdated. Try it.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it solves your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: You really need a larger HDD/SSD**

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p7 (home) and reduce that partition by 5-10G
- **move** the /dev/nvme0n1p7 (home) partition all the way right
- **move** the /dev/nvme0n1p6 (swap) partition all the way right
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p5 (/) all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: Update, it worked fine, Thank you

Comment: @KSplitX Good news! Thanks!